# Match function duplicate values

Tags: r

I was wondering if there is a function in R will help me deal with the problem match function will create if two datasets have duplicating values?

For example,

```
x=c(1,2,2,3,3)
y=c(2,2,3)
```

and I want to keep all the 2,2,3,3 in X but only list 2,2,3 in Y and I still want them to be arranged in order.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to do exactly, maybe `indx <- intersect(x, y) ; x[x %in% indx] ; y[y %in% indx]` helps?

Answer (score 0):

```
    x[which(x %in% y)]
    y[which(y %in% x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#crate some objects to match
x<-data.frame(fruits = c("apples", "bananas", "oranges", "apples"), values = c(1,2,3,4))
y<-data.frame(fruits = c("apples", "oranges", "bananas"), colors = c("red", "pink", "green" )
# x$color will be the new column in x with relevant values from y
# ifelse is a simple condition - if a fruit is found in y, it gets the color from y, if there is nothing to match, it gets an NA 
x$color<-ifelse(x$fruits %in% y$fruits,as.character(y$colors), NA)
x
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value

Comment: to use %in% you might need something from tidyverse, for example library(dplyr)